# How to redirect blog home page if post id empty or not exist in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing blog website by using `Codeigniter`. When I click `category` it shows all post category-wise, but I want it to redirect to the blog home page if the post ID does not exists or empty at url.

How can I do this in Codeigniter?

In row PHP we could use the `$_Get` method for checking post ID is set or empty. If it was empty or does not exist then we can redirect to the home page by using the `header()` method.

So, how will I do redirect in `Codeigniter`?

Comment: You shouldn't do redirects in 404 situations (at least not serverside). It would be better if you present a 404 page with a link to the blog home page instead.

Comment: @Repox Ok then  Can you give any suggestion how will i redirect 404 page in Codeigniter if post id is empty or not exsits?

Comment: You shouldn't 'redirect' in this case. Just add the 404 HTTP header and show a "page not found" view. See here: https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/general/errors.html#id5

Comment: you can simple use the `redirect(base_url() . 'Controller/function_name');` .

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have something like:

`/blog/post/some-post-title`

Well, that's fine. `some-post-title` exists, and everything works.

Now let's say we have `/blog/post/123` where 123 doesn't exist. Well, we can either server our typical 404 (preferred and automatic) or do something else; which sounds like what you want.

In that case all we need to do is to check if, first, anything exists after `/post/` and whether or not the slug or id actually exists in the database table.

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

    public function post($slug = null) {

        if (is_null($slug) || $this->blog_model->exists($slug)) {
            redirect('/blog');
        }
        ... load your views... whatever

    }

}

class Blog_model extends CI_Model {

    public function exists($slug) {
        $this->db->where('slug', $slug);
        return $this->db->count_all_results('blog_db_table') == 1;
    }

}
```

Obviously you will have to adapt this to your specific schema.